# How to remove this weird default indentation?

Tags: indentation

If I do `gg=G` on a file with the following text

```
- 2018-2019 ICPC Northwestern European Regional Programming Contest (NWERC 2018)

- 2020 ICPC Universidad Nacional de Colombia Programming Contest

- 2018-2019 ICPC Southwestern European Regional Programming Contest (SWERC 2018)
```

it becomes

```
- 2018-2019 ICPC Northwestern European Regional Programming Contest (NWERC 2018)

    - 2020 ICPC Universidad Nacional de Colombia Programming Contest

- 2018-2019 ICPC Southwestern European Regional Programming Contest (SWERC 2018)
```

I have executed vim with no configuration files (`vim -u NONE`) and this still happens.

Comment: What does `:verbose setlocal filetype? indentexpr? autoindent? cindent? softtabstop? tabstop? shiftwidth? expandtab?` say?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have executed vanilla vim without configurations, so it says `filetype=
  indentexpr=
noautoindent
nocindent
  softtabstop=0
  tabstop=8
  shiftwidth=8
noexpandtab`

Comment: I'm guessing it's the parens in the first line. Probably being confused for a function or other code construct since Vim has a code-centric indentation scheme by default, I believe.

Comment: I missed `:verbose setl equalprg?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a misuse of `=` operator.

Actually, Vim has two builtin "formatting" operators, i.e. `=` and `gq` (there's also `gw` that is simply the same as "internal" `gq`-formatter).

`=` is supposed for use with programming languages. Of course, it could be set up to do anything you like, but it defaults to C. Does it come as surprise? I don't think so.

So I suggest simply to stop using `=` for plain text formatting and switch to `gq` / `gw` instead.

If you still like doing it with `=`, you have to provide non-default values for `indentexpr` or `equalprg`, whichever you choose.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use "fake" `indentexpr` value:

```
set indentexpr=-1
```

Having this applied to a filetype (or a buffer without filetype) will make `==` and friends (`gg=G`, `=ip`, etc) never change existing indentation.

I had similar problem with a mappings that move lines/selection up and down reindenting after each move (like if a line ends up in an `if` block, it is reindented properly). It worked OK for most of the filetypes but for some it didn't. Those were the ones with default indentation method -- and yes it was list like items too :).

**upd**

mappings were

```
" Move line up/down
nnoremap <silent> <C-j> :<C-u>silent! move+1<CR>==
nnoremap <silent> <C-k> :<C-u>silent! move-2<CR>==
" Move selected lines up/down
xnoremap <silent> <C-j> :move'>+<CR>gv=gv
xnoremap <silent> <C-k> :move-2<CR>gv=gv
```

Comment: Hey, would mind sharing that mapping somehow? It sounds great!

Comment: @Biggybi, updated