# Vim treats paths with wildcards( /*) as C-style block comments and applies weird indentation

Tags: indentation

`Vim 8.1` from `Ubuntu 20.04` thinks `/*` in `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` is a start of a C-style block comment and gives wrong indentation in default `nginx.conf` file when using '=':

```
http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        ...
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
                                   }
```

Is it possible to fix this besides giving custom `indentexpr`?

Comment: Are you sure the `filetype` is set correct? It looks like it's somehow set to something different than `nginx`. What does `set filetype? indentexpr? syntax?` output? What is the path of the file you're editing?

Comment: I don't get an `nginx` filetype when testing @MartinTournoij ; heck, `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` doesn't even contain `nginx`. `:setf apache` is mildly better, but doesn't fix the last curly brace (I would remove the ellipses before testing, though, as they interfere with subsequent lines).

Comment: @MartinTournoij Vim was written with little besides C-programs in mind. I think `Neovim` team should have been go deeper and rewrite it all from scratch on Rust. But anyway, big thanks to them

Comment: Eh? Vim supports many different filetypes, and has for decades.

Comment: @MartinTournoij It supports it via stuff from $VIMRUNTIME written on `VimScript`. In its 'C'-core it supports mainly C

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34784/how-to-remove-this-weird-default-indentation)

Comment: Not exactly. My question is related to `nginx` and the answer contains the link to the solid `indentexpr` solution

Comment: It's not a "patch". You mean a link to a custom nginx ftplugin that, besides other things, provides custom indentexpr. But I think it's obvious that one either writes one of his own or searches through the web for stuff already done by someone else. Vim already delegates nearly all language-related features to plugins. And many of them are shipped together with Vim. But it's impossible to support just everything. Normally Bram accepts new ftplugins only if there is a person who is willing to maintain them.

Comment: yes, strictly speaking that's not a patch, but a pull request, which contains patch as its core integral part. It doesn't matter how exactly this thing is called, what matters is that it solves the problem. AFAIU the more links to some resource do present in the WEB, the more chances it will be indexed and found through search engines. So if somebody will ever have an issue similar to mine and do google or go directly to this website, they are likely to find this question and have their issue solved.

Comment: Speaking about language support, I was just a little bit upset that `set nocindent` doesn't actully disable C-indent even if the user code on non-C.

Comment: And such imposed С-support messes things up.
But I understand perfectly well that the creation of an editor like Vim is a huge work the author had faced and had to resolve tons of tradeoffs, so such inconsistences would be inevitable. I appreciate Bram work just like all the Vim users

Comment: 1. It's a pull request to a 3rd party plugin. Not present in Vim distribution at all. 2. It does for most purposes. Except "equal" operator. 3. User expects the "equal" operator to do at least something. But if indentexpr is not set then what should it do? There's no perfect solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131358/discussion-between-matt-and-vatosarmat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, seems it is not possible. As we can see from [the source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/113cb513f76d8866cbb6dc85fa18aded753e01da/src/ops.c#L4007), Vim operator `=` just indents *everything* as a C-program if neither `lisp` nor `equalprg` nor `indentexpr` is set. [Main C-indenting function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/113cb513f76d8866cbb6dc85fa18aded753e01da/src/cindent.c#L2034) doesn't seem to have and block-comments disabling options.
Here is [the patch](https://github.com/chr4/nginx.vim/pull/20) with proper `indentexpr`